# Try to block tabs in ms-settings for Windows 10 OS

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I try currently to disable some tabs of the ms-settings software included in Windows 10 OS. I'm working with two versions of W10 (W10 LTSB 2015 => v1507 and W10 PRO v1607).

In fact I would like to allow Windows Update for all users and disable the others functions for everybody.

As you maybe know, this is not possible to handle ms-settings: with GPO or gpedit and I have to make it work with my own methods.

I tried to do these things :
- Handle security strategies of Dll and Exe who are used by ms-settings:windowsupdate (Dll and Exe that I found in registry) -> this was a test to do it to the others functions.
- Used applocker to allow package application windows.immersivecontrolpanel.windowsupdate.
- Delete regedit keys, DWORD, ... to only authorize the access to Windows Update tab.

All these things I tried doesn't work, I can still have access to all the functions of ms-settings:

I can't find anything about that except to repair the ms-settings software when it doesn't work.

Hope you'll help me with this very painfull problem.

Best regards,

Comment: You can restrict control panel items with Group Policies. You'll need to make sure you have the correct Polices installed for the target OS

Answer (score 0):

Run `gpedit.msc`, go to `Computer Configuration`->`Administrative Templates`->`Control Panel` and activate `Settings Page Visibility` and add here entries you want to hide or only show:

[image]

> This policy has two modes: it can either specify a list of settings
>   pages to show or a list of pages to hide. To specify a list of pages
>   to show, the policy string must begin with "showonly:" (without
>   quotes), and to specify a list of pages to hide, it must begin with
>   "hide:". If a page in a showonly list would normally be hidden for
>   other reasons (such as a missing hardware device), this policy will
>   not force that page to appear. After this, the policy string must
>   contain a semicolon-delimited list of settings page identifiers. The
>   identifier for any given settings page is the published URI for that
>   page, minus the "ms-settings:" protocol part.
>
> Example: to specify that only the About and Bluetooth pages should be
>   shown (their respective URIs are ms-settings:about and
>   ms-settings:bluetooth) and all other pages hidden:
>
> showonly:about;bluetooth
>
> Example: to specify that only the Bluetooth page (which has URI
>   ms-settings:bluetooth) should be hidden:
>
> hide:bluetooth

So enter hide:TABNAME which yoou want to hide. Here is a list of all pages:

- about
- activation
- appsfeatures
- appsforwebsites
- backup
- batterysaver
- bluetooth
- colors
- cortana
- datausage
- dateandtime
- defaultapps
- developers
- deviceencryption
- display
- emailandaccounts
- extras
- findmydevice
- lockscreen
- maps
- network-ethernet
- network-mobilehotspot
- network-proxy
- network-vpn
- network-directaccess
- network-wifi
- notifications
- optionalfeatures
- powersleep
- printers
- privacy
- personalization
- recovery
- regionlanguage
- storagesense
- tabletmode
- taskbar
- themes
- troubleshoot
- typing
- usb
- windowsdefender
- windowsinsider
- windowsupdate
- yourinfo

Comment: OK so I had to have a version of Windows at least equal to the version 15002. So it is normal (with my 14393 build version) that I don't get this security strategy.

Because I can't upgrade my Windows OS, I'll try to copy the ADMX file in my PolicyDefinition folder and pray for make it work with my old version.

Comment: ok, I already use Windows 10 Creators update 15063 for my Win10 VM. Is updating no option?

Comment: I'm thinking about upgrade but it'll be really hard to me because this system running under LTSB version and this version is not yet released in 1703/1704 build. I tried to copy all the needed Dlls and softwares related to immersivecontrolpanel but now my OS is crashing. I'll now try to upgrade my LTSB system to Enterprise CB OS and see if I can handle it.

Comment: I think for 1703 there won't be released as LTSB version, only for next version in September 2017. For 1511 there was also no LTSB. In this case wait for next LTSB version in September 2017